# sbt WSDL is unable to compile SOAP client due to name conflict. What should I do?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, sbt

Let me explain things begin with. We're trying to work with a SOAP API Service, by this url:

> http://onepointdemo.myfarebox.com/V2/OnePoint.svc?singleWsdl

We try to compile it with [sbt WSDL](http://downloads.typesafe.com/rp/play-soap/SbtWsdl.html), no option added. It failed. Here is what the errors look like

```
[error] /Users/catfly/our-project/target/scala-2.11/wsdl/main/sources/org/datacontract/schemas/_2004/_07/mystifly/ArrayOfEticket.java:35: ArrayOfEticket is already defined as object ArrayOfEticket
[error] public class ArrayOfEticket {
[error]              ^
[error] /Users/catfly/our-project/target/scala-2.11/wsdl/main/sources/org/datacontract/schemas/_2004/_07/mystifly/Eticket.java:36: Eticket is already defined as object Eticket
[error] public class Eticket {
[error]              ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 19 s, completed Feb 26, 2018 6:03:43 PM
```

We dig into the WSDL file above, and indeed found that there are `ETicket` and `Eticket` in the same schema, as well as `ArrayOfETicket` and `ArrayOfEticket`. This should be enough to make the compiler screams.

My question is, is there any workaround? Or should I ask our service provider to fix naming issues? Thank you!

Comment: The names are so similar that I'd advise against a workaround.

Comment: It's probable imo... since the service will be compiled into .java file, I could peek at the other file and write an another `Eticket` file myself (with some other name of course) to avoid name conflict.

Comment: I just hope someone knows an alternative to this, since that sounds too buggy to do. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding sbt-wsdl compiling option below to build.sbt, then compile the service again.

```
WsdlKeys.wsdlToCodeArgs += "-autoNameResolution"
```